# Magento connect stuck on "Checking dependencies of packages" while upgrading

Tags: php, magento, upgrade, magento-1.9

I am trying to update my `Magento 1.9.1.0` to  `1.9.2.2 (stable)` by Magento connect. but every time it stuck with the console message `Checking dependencies of packages`. I checked all file and folder permissions and they are up to mark. I also tried to set permission once again by the code [magento set permission](http://urfusion.net/set-permission-for-magento-magento-cleaning/). but facing the same issue.

below are the solution I tried but not success.

1. http://urfusion.net/set-permission-for-magento-magento-cleaning/
2. https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Extensions/Magento-connect-stucks-at-Checking-dependencies-of-packages/td-p/8899/page/2
3. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24120/unable-to-install-any-extension-using-magento-connect-manager-no-answer

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have custom admin URL, will this cause the issue?

While I successfully upgraded on local. 
**On Server Magento is not on `root`. It is in `/example.com`**

I am able to update other extensions like :

[image]